# JWT authentication for Django rest framework --> error ={ "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." }

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm using JWT for authentication and I can't make this error go away...

```
HTTP 401 Unauthorized
Allow: GET, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="api"

{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

Below are all my code files...
I think the error is in the simple_jwt section in the settings file but can't figure out what. I looked up a few stackoverflow answers already but nothing seem to work out in my case.

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
}


from datetime import timedelta
from django.conf import settings

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=30),
    # 'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': settings.SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,
    'JWK_URL': None,
    'LEEWAY': 0,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken, Token 
from .models import Book


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    _id = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    isAdmin = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', '_id', 'email', 'username', 'name', 'isAdmin']

    def get__id(self, obj):
        return obj.id

    def get_isAdmin(self, obj):
        return obj.is_staff   

    def get_name(self, obj):
        name = obj.first_name
        if name == '':
            name = obj.email
        return name

class UserSerializerWithToken(UserSerializer):
    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', '_id', 'email', 'username', 'name', 'isAdmin', 'token']

    def get_token(self, obj):
        token = RefreshToken.for_user(obj)
        return str(token.access_token)

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
from django.db.models.fields import BooleanField
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from rest_framework import status

from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, IsAdminUser
from rest_framework.response import Response

from BL.models import Book
from BL.books import books
from BL.serializers import BookSerializer

from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def getBooks(request):
    books = Book.objects.all()
    serializer = BookSerializer(books, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def getBook(request, bk):
    book = Book.objects.all()
    serializer = BookSerializer(book, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from BL.views import book_views as views
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
)

urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.getBooks, name="books"),    
    path('<str:bk>', views.getBook, name="book") 

]
```

Answer (score 0):

You did all correct except you need to add login url too in urlpatterns since you are not allowing the view to be viewed without being loogged in try logging in using api/token url and use access token you will be able to be logged.

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.getBooks, name="books"),    
    path('<str:bk>', views.getBook, name="book"),
    path('api/token/', jwt_views.TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', jwt_views.TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),


]
```